# Jquery Bootstrap Label Display once in a column

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dictionary search.I have to do designing.Here if there is  a noun word ,the noun label should be displayed once not everywhere . For labels I designed using bootstrap.But When the word is  an adjective then the 1st column contains the adjective label.What I am saying is if a  word is noun then noun label should be displayed once in the label in a table column.So, I created the label but it is iterating thorughout or the label is displayed throughout.That should not be the case.Please help me.This should be same for adjectives,adverbs.I have to use using Jquery

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: There is a table If a word is  a noun a label written noun is displayed in first column .If i display Angry word corresponding nouns would be displayed.But I want to display noun label once even if there are many nouns of angry word. I have to do fro adjetives,adverbs as well.